# Coordinate charts on converging Riemann surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, cv.complex-variables, riemann-surfaces

Let $S$ be a $2-$dim manifold and $q \in S$. Furthermore, let $j_{n}$ be a sequence of complex structures on $S$ converging in $C^{\infty}_{\text{loc}}$ to a complex structure $j$ on $S$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Furthermore, let $h_{n}, h$ be metrics of scalar curvature $-1$ compatible with $j_{n},\forall n$ and $j$ respectively, i.e. they are Poincare metrics with respect to the complex structures. Also assume that $h_{n}$ converges to $h$ in $C^{\infty}_{\text{loc}}$.

Question: Does there exists open neighbourhoods $U_{n},U\subset S$ of $q$ and biholomorphisms $f_{n}:(D,i)\rightarrow (U_{n},j_{n}),f:(D,i)\rightarrow (U,j),\forall n$ such that:
1) $f_{n}(0)=q,\forall n$ and  $f(0)=q$;
2) $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ in $C^{\infty}_{\text{loc}}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

I think the assumption on the metrics is not necessary, but I am not sure. Can this above statement be true? Do you know any reference on this? Hope for some answers.

Cheers,
Tobi

Comment: You might try to construct a solution of a boundary value problem on a disk around $q$, using the notion of Maslov index, near the point $q$, to build a convergent sequence of holomorphic functions, and then see if you can force them to be invertible somehow.

Comment: What do you mean by maslov index? jow to construct the solution of boundary value problem using maslov index?

Comment: @ Ben McKay: I do not understand your comment. Can you explain, please?

Comment: If you specify boundary values around a disk for the real part of a holomorphic function, and specify the value of the imaginary part at a single point $q$, that will define a unique holomorphic function (if I remember correctly). Pick a local holomorphic coordinate function for $j$, and take its boundary values around a disk, and then, for each $j_n$, find the holomorphic function with those boundary values. The number of zeroes inside the disk (with multiplicities) is given by the Maslov index on the boundary. So it stays one, i.e. you still have a coordinate function for $j_n$.

Comment: @ Ben McKey: For what is the maslov index needed ?

Comment: @ Ben McKey: is it possible to construct holomorphic functions with respect to $j_{n}$ with the same boundary values as for $j$? If yes why?

Comment: @ Ben McKey: ignore my last question. I know how it is possible to construct the solutions. I have one more question: after constucting the solutions $f_{n}$ and $f$, why do we have convergence i.e. $f_{n} rightarrow f$?

Comment: I believe that if you have very close Laplace operators (from very close metrics), satisfied by the real parts of the $f_n$, then interior Schauder estimates (see Aubin, Some Nonlinear Problems, p. 88) show that the solutions are very close.

Comment: @ Ben McKey: I do not see how Schauder estimates imply convergence.

Comment: @ Ben McKey: I do not see how to get them $C^{0}$ close to each other. Of course, if one has this it would imply convergence also for higher derivatives.

Comment: @ Ben McKey: I see now ... I think I have it ... thanks!!!